# Hardware independent docker image with GUI application

Tags: java, docker, nvidia

I'm trying to build a docker image with Java GUI application inside running on Ubuntu. I'm using X server from the host, which seems natural and is recommended by many guides. The problem that I'm facing is that on computers with NVIDIA graphics it seems that X server on the host is aware that there's NVIDIA graphic card and I got exceptions when starting 3D apps. I can install nvidia drivers inside, but this makes it hardware specific and wouldn't work on computers with nvidia.

Is there a way to not use hardware accelerators (like nvidia) and thus make it portable between computers?

Comment: I'd just run the jar file and not involve Docker at all.  Is there a specific reason you want Docker here?

Comment: Docker image makes it much easier to distribute, solve dependencies, handle versioning and be consistent with other software which we're using. It has a number of advantages.